# ReflectionException (-1) Class App\Http\Controllers\IndexController does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

in my localhost its work perfect but once i upload  in server the index page showing like this

> ReflectionException (-1) Class App\Http\Controllers\IndexController does not exist

my route

```
Route::get('/Shop/{id}', 'IndexController@index');
Route::get('/Shop/{id}/products/{pid}/details', 'ProductController@details');
```

controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\support\Facades\Http;

class Indexcontroller extends Controller
{
    public function index($id,Request $request)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Indexcontroller` replace with `IndexController`. PHP is case-sensitive.

Comment: Ulianka Shu not understand can you explain

Comment: On the las line you have `class Indexcontroller extends Controller ...`, where IndexController has small C.